# Modifying a Vector inside a Loop with C++ and the C# Analog

Tags: c#, c++

I am not familiar with removing items from vectors on the fly in C++ and I have the requirement to translate a block of code to C#. The following code is the C++

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
  if (vertices[i].z < 0) { // make hemisphere
      vertices.erase(vertices.begin() + i);

      // delete all triangles with vertex_i
      int t = 0;
      for (std::deque<unsigned int>::iterator it = triangles.begin();
          it != triangles.end();) {
          if (triangles[t] == i || triangles[t + 1] == i ||
              triangles[t + 2] == i) {
              it = triangles.erase(it);
              it = triangles.erase(it);
              it = triangles.erase(it);
          }
          else {
              ++it;
              ++it;
              ++it;
              t += 3;
          }
      }
      // update indices
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < triangles.size(); j++) {
          if (triangles[j] > i) {
              triangles[j]--;
          }
      }
      i--;
  }    
// More code here...
```

where

```
std::vector<Vector3d> vertices;
std::deque<unsigned int> triangles;
```

My confusion comes in where removal is occurring from within the loop. Take this line

```
vertices.erase(vertices.begin() + i);
```

This is equivalent to `List<Vector3>` `RemoveAt(i)` method, but in C# this cannot be done inside the loop. What would be the easiest way to construct this code in C# with as little change to the logic and flow as possible?

Comment: It *can* be done inside the loop since you aren't using an actual iterator, just an index and a count. The one's inside the iterator loop (the inner-for) will have that problem though.

Comment: The code  is doing something complex. This class is doing something using four methods and 400 lines, yet deserves a 8 page academic paper to describe it. For this aspect of this work, I merely would like to translate/port this C++ to C#, the problem is that way this C++ is working with iterators. It is weirding me out.

Comment: *// delete all triangles with vertex_i* -- `auto iter = std::remove_if(triangle.begin(), triangle.end(), [&](int n) { return n == i; });` then `triangle.erase(iter, triangle.end());` -- This is a two line operation in C++, not a complex loop.  It looks like whoever authored this code is not familiar with STL algorithm functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop can be simplified a lot, in C# this should be pretty easy:

So for the inner loop, we can do the same in C#:

```
for (int it = 0; it < triangles.Count;)
{
    if (triangles[t] == i || triangles[t+1] == i || triangles[t+2] == i)
    {
        triangles.RemoveRange(it, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        it += 3;
        t += 3;
    }
}
```

Notice there is no increment term in the `for` loop, this is taken care of in the `else` statement. We can remove items from the list here because `.Count` will always be evaluated each iteration. We are not modifying a list we are iterating on because there is no active iterator (this would be different if we used a `foreach` loop).

So you can do the same for the outer loop, where it shows `vertices.erase(vertices.begin() + i);` you can just replace it in C# with `vertices.RemoveAt(i)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. You time is most appreciated.